# Multiple logfactory instances, is it performance safe?

Tags: .net-core, nlog

I am using NLog with .netcore31 web api hosted in IIS10.

[We are following a design](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/04/running-multiple-independent-asp-net-core-pipelines-side-by-side-in-the-same-application/) by [Filip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1437642/filip-w) that allows running parallel and independent pipelines within an application for each application area/branch.

I would like to configure individual nlog.config files for each of the independent pipeline so that each of them has its own logging configuration and logging filters/targets etc.

I am using following code to configure separate nlog.config for each branch -

//sample Code - for each branch/pipeline

```
var webHostBuilder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddNLog(serviceProvider => new LogFactory(nLogConfigFilePathForBranch))
    })
```

I have 18 such branches configured in the application.
I have not used UseNLog() method anywhere in the code.

Under load (200 concurrent requests) the response time of the application is very low and application is stalled for first 4-5 mins and then responds at very slow speed. There is one "Select" query on single view (select 1 record from roughly 500 records) in the functionality.

I also see an error in NLog internal log - "Warn Flush completed with errors Exception: System.TimeoutException: Timeout when flushing all targets, after waiting 15 seconds."

I am using following Nuget pckgs -

```
<PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.7.4" />
<PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.9.3" />
<PackageReference Include="NLog.WindowsEventLog" Version="4.7.4" />
```

NLog.Config typically looks like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true" internalLogLevel="off" internalLogFile="admin.internalLog.txt">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" />
    <add assembly="NLog.WindowsEventLog" />
    <add assembly="Sirius.Api.Platform.Common" />
  </extensions>
  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="EventLog" name="apiEventlog" source="Api.Travel" layout="${api-traceidentifier}|${api-userid}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" Log="Application" machinename="."/>
    <!-- write to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="Api.Travel" fileName="Logs\Api.Travel\${shortdate}.log" keepFileOpen="true" openFileCacheTimeout="120"
        layout="${longdate}|${api-traceidentifier}|${uppercase:${level}}|${api-userid}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
  </targets>
  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="Api.Travel" />
    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Info"  writeTo="Api.Travel" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="apiEventlog" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

api-traceidentifier and api-userid are layout renderer as follows -

```
[LayoutRenderer("api-traceidentifier")]
[ThreadSafe]
internal class ApiUserLogin_RequestTokenLayoutRenderer : AspNetLayoutRendererBase
{
    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContextAccessor?.HttpContext;
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            Guid traceId = System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId;
            var identifier = Convert.ToBase64String(traceId.ToByteArray()).Replace("=", "").Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_");
            builder.Append(identifier);
        }
        else
        {
            base.Append(builder, logEvent);
        }
    }
    protected override void DoAppend(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        builder.Append(LookupTraceIdentifier(httpContext));
    }
    private string LookupTraceIdentifier(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var traceId = Guid.Empty;
        if (Guid.TryParse(httpContext.TraceIdentifier, out traceId))
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(traceId.ToByteArray()).Replace("=", "").Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_");
        }
        return httpContext.TraceIdentifier;
    }

}
```

I would like to know if this approach is correct, if its performance safe. If not, will anyone pls be able to suggest any different approach.

Comment: Good job on activating the NLog InternalLogger. The warning about flush-timout is strange, since you should not explictly call `Flush()` so check your source code. Also make sure that you are not constantly assigning new NLog-Configuration. Maybe turn-off `autoreload="true"` to see if something triggers automatic reload.

Comment: And to answer your question. There is no problem with having 18 isolated LogFactory-instances.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4490